# MySQL: Swap ID between two rows

Tags: mysql, update

We have existing table:

---

```
| id |    name    |   color   | calories |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | apple      | red       | 20       |
| 2  | orange     | orange    | 10       |
| 3  | grapes     | green     | 5        |
| 4  | bananas    | yellow    | 15       |
| 5  | plum       | purple    | 25       |
------------------------------------------
```

Column `id`  is unique and primary key. I'm facing a problem with edit/update records when, i heed to change for example in row 3 where, `id = 3` to `id = 5` and row 5 where, `id = 5` to `id = 3`... Like swap id between rows 3 and 5. Of course there are duplicate, but how to resolve this scenario...

But MySQL logically throws out the error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I know it is stupid scenario, but we have a customer who wants it that way. He want to edit/update each existing records.

Comment: Is the FK deferrable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These should be wrapped in a transaction using an intermediate value;

```
begin;
set @from = 3;
set @to = 5;
set @tmpid = (2000000 + @from % 147483647);
update col set id=@tmpid where id = @from;
update col set id=@from where id=@to;
update col set id=@to where id = @tmpid;
commit;
```

Choosing a high end @tmpid namespace to avoid collisions is important not to run into trouble later.

Answer (score 17):

> Column id is unique and primary key ... Like swap id between rows 3 and 5.

You *should not* do this.

The Primary Key of any record should be created/set/generated when the record is first created and it should *never* change, not for the *entire lifetime* of that record, right up to the point when the record is finally deleted.

Imagine the chaos if banks *renumbered* people's bank accounts!

Also, while you don't appear to have them here (yet), one of the main benefits of having a Primary Key is that *other tables* can have Foreign Keys that refer to it.   If you start changing the Primary Key value, then you **have** to change all the corresponding Foreign Key values as well (the database will enforce this).
I seriously doubt any User will understand this.

> ... customer ... want to edit/update each existing records.

By all means allow them to edit the data, just *not* the Primary Key.
I'm going to assume that you're providing some sort of UI for this and that they're *not* issuing SQL directly against the database.

If they're trying to use it as some sort of sequence or "order", then using a *separate column* is the way to go.  Primary Keys, even auto-increment ones, are guaranteed to be *unique*; they are *not* guaranteed to be sequential or contiguous.

Comment: While I generally agree with your statement, that is not practical for all cases. For example, what if someone inserts two rows in the wrong order, and the table is more of a reference table like Phone Number Type or a table of Countries?  This would especially be helpful if there is other business logic hardcoded to the specific PK Id

Comment: "what if someone inserts two rows in the /wrong order/ ...": 
Rows in relational database tables have *no intrinsic order*.  
Primary Keys should not be used to control the "ordering" of rows because they are /not/ guaranteed to be sequential or contiguous.  If you want a "sequence" column, then create your own.

Answer (score 2):

I concur that it is alw2ays a bad idea to change the ids especially when they are used in foreign keys..

I also not very happy with the triangle swap.

So when you try to update old ids and are **very sure** that have made a backup  and have thought about all consequences that will imply.

you can use a stored procedure, which will be saver(example borrowed from Charlieface)

> ```
> create table t(id int UNIQUE,v varchar(10));
> ```

> ```
> insert into t (id,v)
> values (2,'c'),(3,'a'), (5,'b');
> ```

> ```
> select * from t
> ```
>
> ```
> id | v 
> -: | :-
>  2 | c 
>  3 | a 
>  5 | b
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name(IN _a BIGint , IN _b BIGint)
> BEGIN
>    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE T1 SELECT _b,v  FROM t WHERE id = _a;
>    DELETE FROM t WHERE id = _a;
>    UPDATE t SET id = _a WHERE id = _b;
>    INSERT INTO t SELECT * FROM T1;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL procedure_name(3,5)
> ```

> ```
> select * from t
> ```
>
> ```
> id | v 
> -: | :-
>  2 | c 
>  3 | b 
>  5 | a
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1286dbb0574faa9df93af1ec269d8617)*

Answer (score 1):

You can do the update as a *single* statement, but this only works in SQL Server, not MySQL

```
update col
set id = case when id = 3 then 5 else 3 end
where id in (3, 5);
```

[SQL Server db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ffc4cb46ebe42c905a09a9d581fd654e)

[MySQL db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffc4cb46ebe42c905a09a9d581fd654e)

---

In SQL Server, an `update` to the primary key (or any unique key) is evaluated at statement-level. It does this internally by using a `Split->Sort->Collapse` plan, which means that it effectively becomes a delete, an update, and an insert, and there is therefore no constraint violation.

See also these two articles [by Paul White](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/12/beware-sneaky-reads-with-unique-indexes.html) and [Fabiano Amorim](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/showplan-operator-of-the-week-split-sort-collapse/)

---

A correct implementation of constraints would have the `IMMEDIATE` or `DEFERRED` options. Both of these require constraint checking at the *statement* level, not the *row* level.

MySQL supports neither, because it checks constraints on a row-by-row basis. PostgreSQL also checks `IMMEDIATE` constraints on a row level

But SQL Server only checks on a statement level. You can see this in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_standards/ms-tsqliso02/70d6050a-28c7-4fae-a205-200ccb363522).

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, swapping IDs doesn't make any sense.

I think the best approach for this particular customer is to let them make edits (e.g. in a spreadsheet) and then truncate the table and re-insert the rows that the customer has specified.